# I have a issue which is that I use TabularInline django 1.7 does not let me save

Tags: python, django

[image]

[image]

I have a problem which is that I use TabularInline Django 1.7 does not let me save shows me everything perfectly to give to keep me throws an error this is problem that I utlizando another database other than the default and exception throws me that the table does not exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the images aren't very clear, but what I understand from your description of the problem is that the models do not have corresponding tables in the database. Please check/ share your configuration in settings.py and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If there is still any issues, please share more information